# Is $f(x)=x$ the solution of an integral equation?

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Suppose that $f:[0, \infty)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x) \neq 0 $ for all $x>0$. If 
$$
\big(\,f(x)\big)^2=2 \int_0^x f(t)\,dt,
$$ 
for all $x>0$, is it then  true that $f(x)=x$ for all $x\geq 0?$

Please give me a hint.

Comment: hint: differentiate

Comment: What have you tried? We have $x$ as a limit of integration, what does that strongly suggest we use?

Answer (score 2):

Set $g(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$. Then $g(0)=0$, and $g(x)\ne 0$, for all  $x>0$, and as 
$2g(x)=\left(f(x)\right)^2\ge 0$, then $g(x)>0$, for all $x>0$. Also, $g$ is differentiable, as the indefinite integral of a continuous function, and so is its square root $\sqrt{2}\,g^{1/2}(x)=f(x)$, for $x>0$. So $g$ satisfies $g'=\sqrt{2g}$, for $x>0$, and $g(0)=0$.

Thus $g^{-1/2}(x)g'(x)=\sqrt{2}$. But and hence
$$
0=g^{-1/2}(x)g'(x)-\sqrt{2}=\left(2g^{1/2}(x)-\sqrt{2}\,x\right)'
$$
or 
$$
g^{1/2}(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+c,
$$ 
for some constant $c$,
and as $g$ is continuous at $x=0$, and $g(0)=0$, then $c=0$ and $g(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{2}$. Thus 
$$
f(x)=g'(x)=x.
$$

Comment: or do you mean that $g(x)=\frac{(f(x))2}{2}$?

Comment: How did you come up with $g^{(1/2)}=\dfrac{x}{2}+c$?

Comment: @lecnad: See edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus on the RHS. This gives you:
$$
2f'(x)f(x)=2f(x).
$$

Comment: How do you know that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I wrote something about that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to Kim Jong Un's answer, we show that $f$ is differentiable.

RHS in the given equality is obviously differentiable, thus so is $f^2$. Now write $f=\sqrt{f^2}$, and since $f^2(x)\neq0$ for every $x\neq0$, we conclude $f$ is differentiable anywhere but $0$, by the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks for supplementing my answer. Just a comment: I think you should point out that because $f$ is continuous and $f(x)\neq 0$ for $x>0$, then for such $x$, $f$ is always positive or always negative. But the latter would violate $f^2=2\int f$ so $f$ is positive for positive $x$. This justifies $f=\sqrt{f^2}$.

Comment: @KimJongUn You're right, of course. But now that you have pointed it out yourself, I guess I'll add nothing.